# Name for a non-square matrix with ones along the main diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is there a name for a matrix that would be the identity matrix, except that it's not square?  In other words, it has ones along the main diagonal, and zeroes off of the main diagonal.  But as it's not a square matrix, it is not the identity matrix.

Comment: I doubt there is a name...

Comment: @WilliamJockusch What is the diagonal of a non-square matrix?

Comment: I assume he means a matrix whose elements $a_{ij}$ are defined by he kronecker delta $\delta_{ij}$, but isn't necessarily square. That's the best definition I can think of.

Comment: @BenjaminLim: usually, the set of all entries whose row and column indices are equal.  (He's talking about block matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix} I & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ or $\begin{pmatrix} I \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$, where $I$ is a square identity matrix and $0$ is a rectangular zero matrix of the appropriate size.)